# Put JNDI parameter in WebSphere

Tags: python, websphere, jndi

I would like to ask a question. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have a pair, let's say `[key1][value1]` and I would like to put them in a JNDI of WebSphere server using administrative script. What command in Python would do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm just wondering do you know a way to do it over the Integrated Solutions Console?

Comment: I can run a script in a console as far as I know. But unfortunately I do not know the syntax of a Python. Do you?

Comment: IBM has some documentation about its jython scripts. I was just wondering if you know how to configure an easy key value pair for retrival via JNDI.

Comment: One binds a name for a specific object be it DataSource, ConnectionFactory or just a string, right?

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering how to do it for a simple String. The WAS will tell you the script if you do the same steps within the WAS.

Comment: But how to do it with not a simple String by means of console?

Comment: Can these values be application environment entries, or are you trying to create them as WebSphere name space bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. I added spring context to store my values and to enhance architecture.